# Use existing perspective from a different plugin in RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

This is what we have:

- a Plugin with an IPerspectiveFactory implementation and an extension to org.eclipse.ui.perspectives. This works fine if we open the perspective in the Eclipse window that is tarted from this plugin's MANIFEST.MF.
- An Eclipse 4 Application Project (in a different Eclipse project)

I tried to use the existing perspective by adding a perspective to the Eclipse 4 Application Project's PerspectiveStack in the Application.e4xmi. This only results in an empty window.

My next guess was to re-define the existing perspective from within the Application.e4xmi and adding the existing ViewParts using their Class URI (e.g. bundleclass://org.example.myplugin/org.example.myplugin.views.SettingsView). This however resulted in an almost empty window (separators etc. were visible) without my desired ViewPart. I also get Errors of the following form:
"(org.example.myproduct.abc:24070): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 912 was not found when attempting to remove it"

My last attempt was to copy my IPerspectiveFactory implemenation folder into the application project, but then I get errors claiming that IPerspectiveFactory etc. are not API (even though I'm pretty sure I added the same dependencies as in my plugin).

What am I missing?

Comment: So this is an Eclipse 3.x style plugin you are trying to use in a pure e4 application? That is not going to work.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks! I've never found an option to create a plug-in project for Eclipse 4 in the Plug-in Project wizard.
Would you recommend somehow migrating our existing plugins to Eclipse 4 or 'simply' creating an Eclipse 3 RCP application (considering it has to be finished by Friday)?

Comment: Stick to 3.x if you are not familiar with e4 given the short timescale.

Comment: @greg-449 You should add those comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 3.x style plugins (anything using 'org.eclipse.ui.xxxx' plugins or extension points) won't work in a pure e4 RCP. This is because e4 leaves out a lot of the old 3.x compatibility code to make the RCP simpler.

So if you are on a short timescale it is simpler to stick to writing a 3.x style RCP.